# Set Focus on row by cell value

Tags: c#, winforms, gridview, devexpress, devexpress-windows-ui

I have two grid views namely `PositionsReadyListGridView` and `PositionsNotReadyListGridView`.

Now the functionality requirement is on click of Button `Set Not Ready` the selected item from `PositionsReadyListGridView` is removed from this list and added to `PositionsNotReadyListGridView`.

Similarly on click of Button `Set Ready` the selected item from `PositionsNotReadyListGridView` is removed from this list and added to `PositionsReadyListGridView`.

I have implemented this functionality but I am unable to set Focus on the latest row which is added to the either of the GridView.

> Is there a way that I can set Focus to the row according to cell
>   values?

For example in both of the Grids I have a column `colID` which is unique to a row.

Can I somehow use this ID to set Focus to the row added to either `PositionsReadyListGridView` (on Set Ready click) or `PositionsNotReadyListGridView` (on Set Not Ready Click)?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `LocateByValue` method, which returns `RowHandle` of located row and set this value to `FocusedRowHandle` property:

```
int rowHandle = PositionsReadyListGridView.LocateByValue("colID", ID);
if (rowHandle != GridControl.InvalidRowHandle)
    PositionsReadyListGridView.FocusedRowHandle = rowHandle
```

Answer (score 0):

to get the lately added row get it by

```
PositionsReadyListGridView.Rows.Count - 1
```

and for setting the focus

```
PositionsReadyListGridView.Rows[PositionsReadyListGridView.Rows.Count - 1].Cells[colID].Selected = true;
```

Comment: Hi Mohamed, the problem is changes in the list are done at DB Level and after changes are done new lists are binded again to gridviews. So the chances are that the position of new row could be anywhere in the grid.

Comment: Then, try to get the "UpdatedTime" from DB and use that to order your data. else use that to select the updated row

Comment: By saying latest row I meant that user can select multiple rows at a time and set them Ready or NotReady in that case the Focus should be on the last row which is setted to Ready or NotReady but again this last row could be placed anywhere in the GridVews(first,last,middle) as GridViews have Groups and new row will be placed in respective Group.

Comment: When user set them ready/not ready does it hit the database? save and fetch it back and bind to the grid?

Comment: I am not actually resetting the binding just assigning the datasource again to the new list like this :  this.PositionsListInvoiceReadyBindingSource.DataSource = _list_PositionsReady;
            this.PositionsListInvoiceReadyBindingSource.RaiseListChangedEvents = true;
            this.PositionsListInvoiceReadyBindingSource.ResetBindings(resetBindings);

Comment: try to have one more property(DateTime) for this list.
whenever a new row is added to this list add with the time stamp. then it will be easy for you to locate the latest modified row.

Answer (score 0):

```
    private void PositionsNotReadyListGridView_RowsAdded(object sender, DataGridViewRowsAddedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.PositionsNotReadyListGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Selected = true;
    }
```

Comment: Unfortunately no Row_Added Event for GridView I am using. (Devexpress-XtraGrid)

Answer (score 0):

**for devExpress use this code :**

```
gridView1.FocusedRowHandle = gridView1.LocateByValue("columnName",value of columnName, null);
```